# REST URI parameters to filter response

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest

I am trying to filter a list of objects retrieved from the database, as per the parameters retrieved from the REST URI. Example URI would be `http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/employee?FirstName=Abigail&LastName=Ybarra` which would retrieve me a list of objects with specified first names and last names.

The error I am getting while hitting such URI is the following:

```
<ExceptionMessage>
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.NullReferenceException</ExceptionType>

MyWebService.Controllers.EmployeeApiController+<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<ListEmployees>b__0 (MyWebService.Models.Employee x) [0x00000] in <8bf6371a770245f989f67352a05d8bb6>:0 at System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereListIterator`1[TSource].MoveNext () [0x00037] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/external/corefx/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Where.cs:369 at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList
```

The same thing happens for ie. URI `http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/employee?id=3`, while it works as expected for URI `http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/employee/3`. It also works as expected (retrieves all objects from the database) for URI `http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/employee/`.

The only thing not working are the parameters. Here is the code.

**Controller.cs**

```
    [RoutePrefix("api/employee")]
    public class EmployeeApiController : ApiController
    {

        readonly EmployeePersistence persistence;


        public EmployeeApiController()
        {
            persistence = new EmployeePersistence();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("{id:long}")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetEmployee(long id) 
        {
            return Json(persistence.GetEmployee(id));
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("")]
        public IHttpActionResult ListEmployees([FromUri] EmployeeParameters parameters)
        {
            return Json(persistence.GetEmployeeList().Where(x => x.FirstName.Equals(parameters.FirstName)));
        }
    }
}
```

**EmployeeParametes.cs**

```
public class EmployeeParameters
{
    /**
     * First name of the employee.
     */
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    /*
     * Last name of the employee.
     */
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    /**
     * Place of birth of the employee.
     */
    public string BirthPlace { get; set; }

    /**
     * Gender of the employee.
     */
    public int Gender { get; set; }

    /**
     * OIB of the employee.
     */
    public string OIB { get; set; }


    /**
     *  Current place of the employee.
     */
    public string CurrentPlace { get; set; }


    /**
     *  Department code of the employee.
     */
    public string Department { get; set; }

    public EmployeeParameters()
    {
    }
}
```

**Persistence.cs**

```
    public List<Employee> GetEmployeeList()
        {
            string sqlString = "SELECT * FROM Employee";

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlString, conn);

            List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

            using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    employees.Add(ReadFromDatabase(reader));
                }
            }

            return employees;
        }

Employee ReadFromDatabase(MySqlDataReader dataReader)
        {
            if (!dataReader.Read())
            {
                return null;
            }

            string firstName = null;
            string lastName = null;
            string birthPlace = null;
            string currentPlace = null;
            int gender = -1;
            string departmentCode = null;
            string OIB = null;

            try
            {
                firstName = dataReader.GetString(1);
                lastName = dataReader.GetString(2);
                birthPlace = dataReader.GetString(3);
                currentPlace = dataReader.GetString(4);
                gender = dataReader.GetInt32(5);
                departmentCode = dataReader.GetString(6);
                OIB = dataReader.GetString(7);
            }
            catch (SqlNullValueException)
            {
                // log the error
            }

            return new Employee(
                firstName != null ? firstName : "N/A",
                lastName != null ? lastName : "N/A",
                birthPlace != null ? birthPlace : "N/A",
                currentPlace != null ? currentPlace : "N/A",
                gender != -1 ? (gender == 1 ? EmployeeGender.M : EmployeeGender.F) : 
                    EmployeeGender.UNDEFINED,
                departmentCode != null ?
                    DepartmentCodeExtensions.GetEnumValue(DepartmentCode.NONE, departmentCode) :
                    DepartmentCode.NONE,
                OIB != null ? OIB : "N/A"
            );
        }
```

I am guessing that the problem is something with the routes, but not sure exactly what or how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please supply the full stack trace of the exception, along with the full contents of the three .cs files - otherwise, it's hard to tell where the error is.

Comment: @J.N. Updated as requested.

Comment: Have you run through the debugger and verified that it's the Parameters object that is null, and not the `Employees` collection returned by the Persistence class?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the exception appears because the calls to `.Read()` in both the `while`-loop and inside the method `ReadFromDatabase`. You should delete the  `.Read()` call from the latter.

As your code is now, two calls of `.Read()` in the reader is performed before you're extracting data from the reader.
Another problem is that you're putting `null` in your list of employees if the reader can't read more, guaranteeing a `NullPointerException` when trying to use the `FirstName` property of this element.